# sync.WaitGroup 相当をチャネルのみで記述可能？

Tags: go

一般には [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) で実現される並行処理の完了待機を、チャネル( [`chan`](http://www.golang-book.com/10/index.htm#section2) )だけをつかって記述することはできますか？

```go
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
  wg.Add(1)
  go func(i int) {
    // 並行処理[i]
    wg.Done()
  }(i)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: [waitgroup のソース](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/sync/waitgroup.go) を見るとわかりますが、最終的には **`chan` で Mutex を実装する** という問題に帰着しそうですね。

Comment: sync.WaitGroupの内部実装ではセマフォ(`runtime_SemaXXX`)使ってるので、この層より下はnative頼りみたいです。sync.Mutex実装も眺めてみたらやはり同関数を利用してますね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(i))
            fmt.Println("Finish:", i)
            done <- true
        }(i)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        <-done
    }
    close(done)
    fmt.Println("All goroutines are done.")
}
```

なお、別解として以下の様にした場合、

```
func main() {
    done := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * time.Duration(i))
            done <- i
        }(i)
    }

    for i := range done {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
```

<strike>`for loop` が終了した時点で以下の様なエラーが発生してしまいました。</strike>
以下のエラーメッセージを出力して異常終了します。

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

これは、`for ... range done` で 10 個の goroutine から値を取り出した後、さらに channel からデータを読み込もうとしたためです。

Answer (score 2):

ちょっと違うアプローチで。。
goroutineの分だけchannel作ると言う手も。

```
chs := make([]chan struct{}, 10)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    chs[i] = make(chan struct{})
    go func(i int, ch chan struct{}) {
        // 並行処理[i]
        ch <- struct{}{}
    }(i, chs[i])
}

// wait
for _, ch := range chs {
    <-ch
}
```

ちょっとコスト高かもですが、goroutineからerrorや戻り値受け取れるというメリットも。

Answer (score 1):

ぽいものできましたが、そういう質問じゃなかったと気づきました・・・

こういうのは channel の典型的な使い方の一つですか<s>ら簡単ですね</s>。

https://play.golang.org/p/BpITj7r1fA

```go
package main

import "sync"
import . "fmt"
import . "time"
```

```go
type Blockers struct {
  counter int
  mx      sync.Mutex
  waiting bool
  ch      chan bool
}

func NewBlockers() (blockers *Blockers){
  blockers         = &Blockers{}
  blockers.ch      = make(chan bool)
  blockers.mx      = sync.Mutex{}
  blockers.waiting = false
  return blockers
}

func (r *Blockers) Add( additive int) {
  r.mx.Lock()
  r.counter += additive
  r.mx.Unlock()
}

func (r *Blockers) Wait() {
  r.mx.Lock()
  if ( r.counter == 0) {
    r.mx.Unlock()
    return;
  }
  if r.waiting {
    // Wait() 過剰
    panic("\"Wait\"ing already")
  }
  r.waiting = true
  r.mx.Unlock()

  <- r.ch
  r.waiting = false
}

func (r *Blockers) Done() {
  r.mx.Lock()
  defer r.mx.Unlock()

  if  r.counter == 0 {
    // Done() 過剰
    return
  }
  r.counter--
  if r.counter == 0 && r.waiting {
    r.ch <- true
  }
}
```

```go
func main() {
  blockers := NewBlockers()

  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    blockers.Add(1)
    go func(i int) {
      Sleep(Millisecond * 50 * Duration(i))
      Println("Finished:", i)
      blockers.Done()
    }(i)
  }

  blockers.Wait()
}
```

**改訂:** `sync.Mutex` を使うようにしています
**改訂:** チャンネル1回の入出力のみとし、エラーハンドリングなどのコードをちょっと追加

Comment: 厳密にはcounterをmutexで保護したほうが良いですね。

Comment: なるほどー。mutex を使うように修正しました。

Comment: あ…あとこれ `Done()` の呼び出しを goroutine ではなく外=mainでやった時に、`ch` を読み取る人がいないので `Done()` でブロックする予感w …`chan` のバッファ増やしてもその数が限界かも。

Comment: `Wait()`がGoroutine-safeでないのも本来の`WaitGroup`と違いますね。

Comment: なるほどー。指摘助かります。`chan` の使用頻度を減らして、呼び出し順によるブロック発生をなくして、できるだけ Goroutine-safe に修正努力しました。